# like and between in dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a dataframe in which I have to update some value based on some condition.

```
+------+--------+---+-----------+
|std_id|std_name|age|    address|
+------+--------+---+-----------+
|   101| Kishore| 27|     WST RD|
|   102|  Manish| 24|WALLED CITY|
|   103|Himanshu| 23|    TONK RD|
+------+--------+---+-----------+
```

I am updating the value using below script

```
testing.withColumn("std_name", when(col("std_name").equalTo("Kishore"), "Rahul").otherwise(testing("std_name")) )
```

result

```
+------+--------+---+-----------+
|std_id|std_name|age|    address|
+------+--------+---+-----------+
|   101|   Rahul| 27|     WST RD|
|   102|   Anika| 24|WALLED CITY|
|   103|Himanshu| 23|    TONK RD|
+------+--------+---+-----------+
```

but now I want apply condition

> age like %2 -> %5 
>   age between 25 to 27 -> 90

How I can do in Scala, Spark

Comment: What does  age like %2 -> %5  mean ? does it match 2x, 3x, 4x, 5x ? What does age between 25 to 27 -> 90 mean ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

do this,

for between

```
testing.withColumn("age", when(col("age").between(25,27), 90).otherwise(testing("age")) )
```

For like

```
testing.withColumn("age", when(col("age").like("%2"), 876).otherwise(testing("age")) )
```